# Creating Multiple Charts and export to a PDF using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help with R. I will like to create a plot for each part number (Part_No) and plot two lines,
Median_Cum_Total_Spans and Cum_Operation_Span. On the X Axis, I will need the Operation_Description.

I am attaching a excel chart with an example on how this needs to look like. ( or something similar)

[image: See Image on how the chart needs to look like]

Also, creating a PDF document with all the Charts will be the final goal

```
structure(list(Part_No = c("2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1"), Op = c(50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 
500, 600, 700, 800, 1200, 1000, 1100, 1300, 1400), Operation_Description = c("WI 0050   Kit Material", 
"WI 0100   PP&C Kit Release", "WI 0150   Assemble Housing", "WI 0200   Laser Weld Feedthus", 
"WI 0300   Helium Leak Test", "WI 0400   Temperature Shock", 
"WI 0500   Helium Leak Test", "WI 0600   Install Connectors", 
"WI 0700   Install RF Absorber and Getter", "WI 0800   Unit is Classifed CONFIDENTIAL", 
"WI 1200   Prep Digital CCA", "WI 1000   Install Agility CCA", 
"WI 1100   Install Core", "WI 1300   Quality Inspection", "WI 1400   Install Digital CCA"
), Median_Cum_Total_Spans = c(0.000214664351057123, 0.00308969907186649, 
36.8596928240718, 40.9701633680557, 41.0358362847222, 41.8566154745359, 
41.9030351736107, 50.196341799768, 51.1075530844913, 51.1588216782416, 
77.1400124768526, 82.8711324074064, 82.8842914351848, 83.1055626157423, 
83.9270806539348), Stdev_Cum_Total_Spans = c(0.00239299574335345, 
0.00600976705703139, 10.8139048943357, 15.3558862263826, 15.345189110808, 
15.6127521580102, 15.6738532421114, 13.9918390182919, 14.4703213133313, 
13.8827680307732, 21.2042919842159, 33.9105333793707, 33.8942703381567, 
33.5756312668837, 34.469754213964), Median_Operation_Spans = c(0.000214664351057123, 
0.000627858796053463, 0.0183557060167745, 1.10562002893537, 0.0115535300928685, 
0.0191393518516862, 0.0088567129632941, 0.0251588368057101, 0.0180307060190373, 
0.000798437500165569, 1.80241268518484, 0.0060900925927692, 0.0161419444448418, 
0.0132889699080476, 0.00840645833147896), n = c(145L, 145L, 97L, 
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 78L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
110L), Cum_Operation_Span = c(0.000214664351057123, 0.000842523147110586, 
0.0191982291638851, 1.12481825809925, 1.13637178819212, 1.15551114004381, 
1.1643678530071, 1.18952668981281, 1.20755739583185, 1.20835583333202, 
3.01076851851686, 3.01685861110963, 3.03300055555447, 3.04628952546252, 
3.05469598379399), CumQueue = c(2.43945488809238e-19, 0.00224717592475591, 
36.8404945949079, 39.8453451099564, 39.89946449653, 40.7011043344921, 
40.7386673206036, 49.0068151099552, 49.8999956886595, 49.9504658449096, 
74.1292439583358, 79.8542737962968, 79.8512908796304, 80.0592730902798, 
80.8723846701408)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    Part_No = "2352841G1", .rows = structure(list(1:15), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### One plot

This will get you the plot for a single part number:

```
p <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Part_No, Op, Operation_Description), names_to = "metric") %>%
  filter(metric %in% c("Median_Cum_Total_Spans", "Cum_Operation_Span")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Operation_Description, value), y = value, color = metric)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = metric), size = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))

p
```

Which looks like:

[image: single plot]

### Multiple plots - faceting

There are a few ways to automatically output multiple plots. It depends on how many you're making and how you want them to look. One option is to use faceting.

First, I'll simulate data with multiple part numbers in one table:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  bind_rows(., df1 %>% mutate(Part_No = "2352841G2"))

df2 %>% group_by(Part_No) %>% do(head(., n = c(1, 4)))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   Part_No [2]
#  Part_No      Op Operation_Description  Median_Cum_Total_Spans
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                                   <dbl>
#1 2352841G1    50 WI 0050   Kit Material               0.000215
#2 2352841G2    50 WI 0050   Kit Material               0.000215
```

Then you could just add to the code above:

```
p + facet_wrap(facets = "Part_No", ncol = 1)
```

Which will produce this faceted plot:

[image: faceted plot]

And then save this to PDF:

```
ggsave("facet_plot.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
```

However if you have many plots you want to make, this will become fairly cumbersome.

### Multiple plots - paginated PDF

Another option is to generate the plots in a loop where you store them in a list and then save to a single pdf doc (one plot per page). This is already described nicely [here][3].

For your example you might be able to modify this code:

```
# make empty list to catch plots you generate
plot_list <- list()

# enumerate part numbers to list over
part_nums <- unique(df2$Part_No)

# loop over part nums and generate individual plots into list
for (i in seq_along(part_nums)) {
  # generate plot
  plot_list[[i]] <- df2 %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(Part_No, Op, Operation_Description), names_to = "metric") %>%
    filter(Part_No == part_nums[i]) %>%
    filter(metric %in% c("Median_Cum_Total_Spans", "Cum_Operation_Span")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Operation_Description, value), y = value, color = metric)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = metric), size = 1) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
  
  # store name of plot in list
  names(plot_list)[i] <- part_nums[i]
}

# initalize PDF write by setting file name and page dimensions
pdf("plots.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)

# loop through plot_list and print each plot to a separate page
for (i in seq_along(plot_list)) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}

# end PDF write
dev.off()
```

Comment: This is great, Thanks

Comment: Trying to organize the data in ascending order before plotting. I tried arrange(Median_Cum_Total_Spans)%>% but did not work

Comment: df1$Operation_Description <- factor(df1$Operation_Description, levels = df1$Operation_Description[order(df1$Median_Cum_Total_Spans)])
 df1$Operation_Description  
 
 
 
 ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = Operation_Description, y=Median_Cum_Total_Spans, group=1, color="red")) + # define the x axis aesthetic

   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
   geom_line()   #this is working but for only one line

Comment: The example data you gave had only one `Part_no`. How is it organized in your full dataset? Is it all in one long `data.frame` (probably easier to work with) or split into multiple for each part number?

Comment: the original datframe has over 40,000 rows. There are a lot of part numbers.

Comment: OK, in that case, the last part of the solution (paginated PDF) should work for you.

Comment: It work, the only problem is the blueline is not in ascending order

Comment: Ok I just updated the code - I think there was a mistake in the original. I the key change is in the `reorder` call in the `x` of the `aes`. Now it `reorder`s by `value`. Let me know if that solves it.